# locales: modify default time format

Tags: debian, locale

I need to change the default time format on my Debian Wheezy system. I am following [this](http://ccollins.wordpress.com/2009/01/06/how-to-change-date-formats-on-ubuntu/) howto.

I have modified the corresponding lines in `/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US`

```
d_t_fmt "<U0025><U0059><U002D><U0025><U0062><U002D><U0025><U0064><U0020><U0020><U0025><U0054>"
d_fmt   "<U0025><U0059><U002D><U0025><U0062><U002D><U0025><U0064>"
t_fmt   "<U0025><U0054>"
```

Than, I ran the command ro compile locales `localedef -f UTF-8 -i en_US en_US.UTF-8`

My locales in `/etc/default/locale` are set to en_US.UTF-8 :

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
```

but i don't see any effect of my changes (even after restart). Am I missing a step ?

UPDATE:
when I run the command in verbose mode, I get lots of errors:

```
localedef -v -c -f UTF-8 -i custom custom.UTF-8

custom:34: non-symbolic character value should not be used
en_GB:50: non-symbolic character value should not be used
i18n:1756: non-symbolic character value should not be used
en_GB:59: non-symbolic character value should not be used
custom:40: non-symbolic character value should not be used
iso14651_t1:3: non-symbolic character value should not be used
iso14651_t1_common:6323: LC_COLLATE: symbol `pure-ta-zh' not known
translit_neutral:10: non-symbolic character value should not be used
translit_neutral:17: non-symbolic character value should not be used
LC_NAME: field `name_gen' not defined
LC_IDENTIFICATION: no identification for category `LC_MEASUREMENT'
LC_CTYPE: table for class "upper": 10634005407197270931 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "lower": 10634005407197270931 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "alpha": 10634005407197270931 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "digit": 10634005407197270931 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "xdigit": 10634005407197270931 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "space": 10634005407197270931 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "print": 10634005407197270931 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "graph": 10634005407197270931 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "blank": 10634005407197270931 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "cntrl": 10634005407197270931 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "punct": 10634005407197270931 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "alnum": 10634005407197270931 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "combining": 10634005407197270931 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "combining_level3": 10634005407197270931 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for map "toupper": 10634005407197270931 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for map "tolower": 10634005407197270931 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for map "totitle": 10634005407197270931 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for width: 0 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

What does `locale` show? 
If it shows "LC_ALL" set to a value, then you might need to `unset` it.

`unset LC_ALL`

Then try:

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_COLLATE="C"
export LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
```

If it works, add these exports into your `~/.bashrc` file. (and maybe the `unset LC_ALL` command before this too)

```
LC_ALL
    This variable determines the values for all locale categories. The value of the LC_ALL environment variable has precedence over any of the other environment variables starting with LC_ (LC_COLLATE, LC_CTYPE, LC_MESSAGES, LC_MONETARY, LC_NUMERIC, LC_TIME) and the LANG environment variable.
```

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html